# Pre-Order Traversal in Binary Tree not able to understand

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

So, I'm trying to create binary tree using static data.

like below -

```
        (1)
        / \
       /   \
     (2)   (3)
     / \
    /   \
  (4)   (5)
          \
           \
           (6)
```

Here is the TreeNode.java

```
package sandeep.topics.binaryTree;

public class TreeNode {
    int value;
    TreeNode left, right;
    
    public TreeNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

& the BinaryTree.java

```
package sandeep.topics.binaryTrees;

public class BinaryTree {
    static TreeNode root;
    public BinaryTree() {
        
    }
    public BinaryTree(int value) {
        root = new TreeNode(value);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree binaryTree = new BinaryTree();
        // level 0
        binaryTree.root = new TreeNode(1);
        
        // level 1
        TreeNode level_1_left = binaryTree.createLeftChild(root, 2);
        TreeNode level_1_right = binaryTree.createRightChild(root, 3);
        
        // level 2
        TreeNode level_2_left = binaryTree.createLeftChild(level_1_left, 4);
        TreeNode level_2_right = binaryTree.createRightChild(level_1_right, 5);
        
        // level 3
        TreeNode level_3_right =  binaryTree.createRightChild(level_2_right, 6);
        
        
        printTree(root, "root", 1);
    }
    private static TreeNode createLeftChild(TreeNode root, int value) {
        root.left = new TreeNode(value);
        return root.left;
    }
    
    private static TreeNode createRightChild(TreeNode root, int value) {
        root.right = new TreeNode(value);
        return root.right;
    }
    private static void printTree(TreeNode root, String type, int level) {
        if(root == null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(root.value + " : " + type + " : " + level);
        printTree(root.left, "left", level+1);
        printTree(root.right, "right", level+1);
    }
}
```

Very simple code that can create root, children as per level and print them.

Output shown as -

```
(Columns; 1st- node value, 2nd - node type & 3rd - level)


1 : root : 1
2 : left : 2
4 : left : 3
3 : right : 2
5 : right : 3
6 : right : 4
```

Shows - 1 2 4 3 5 6.

But I think, the correct pre-order traversal should be 1 2 4 5 6 3.

Not sure, what am i doing wrong though!

Comment: NB You don't need both `BinaryTree` and a separate `TreeNode` class. A binary tree node is already a binary tree, by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of tree does not match your picture, I guess you wanted to type

```java
TreeNode level_2_right = binaryTree.createRightChild(level_1_left, 5);
```

Otherwise the program seems correct (except that small improvements are possible - unnecessary constructor or assignments etc... it's usually good practice to declare `TreeNode` as immutable with children passed in constructor, which better visualizes tree structure using `new TreeNode(1,new TreeNode(2,new TreeNode(4)...),new TreeNode(3))`, ideally with proper indentation).

Comment: I corrected the mistake as you told now it shows the correct traversal order. Thank you.

Comment: @SandeepRoy I edited answer with unrelated advices. Feel free to accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Tomas, can you guide me a little more about how to pass children as constructors, seems more easier.

Comment: Just create another constructor: `public TreeNode(int value, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {this.value = value; this.left = left; this.right = right;}`. Then the expression for leaf node is `new TreeNode(6)` (your constructor), for nonleaf node `new TreeNode(5, null, new TreeNode(6))` and so on. You actually don't need the `BinaryTree` class unless you want some tree-scope operation (`printTree` can be `TreeNode` method as well).